# Wrapping the window Object to isolate javascript

Tags: javascript

In my current project i'm trying to isolate third-party js but still allow it some dom access, for example if the js code would use "`document.cookie`" it will get an empty string but if it will use "`document.getElementById`" it will get a real node from the dom.
I can't use a regular iframe (with sandbox attribute or whatever) to isolate the code because as i mentioned i need to allow some dom access.
What i'm doing currently is creating a blank iframe and hooking all of it's window/document methods/properties and than injecting the third-party js, but for now i'm struggling with two problems:

1.the window object contains some read-only properties like the `window.top` which i can't hook and for that reason if the js code will call "`window.top`" it will get the top most window instead of the iframe window, i can handle that by wrapping everything in the window object of the iframe like that:

```
//source: https://blog.javascripting.com/2014/05/19/wrapping-the-dom-window-object/

var wrapper = {};  
for (var prop in window) {  
  (function(prop) {
    if (typeof(window[prop]) === 'function')  {
      wrapper[prop] = function() { return window[prop].apply(window, arguments); }
    }
    else {
      Object.defineProperty(wrapper, prop, {
        'get': function() {
          if (window[prop] === window) {
            return wrapper;
          }
          else {
            return window[prop];
          }
        },
        'set': function(value) { wrapper[prop] = value; }
      });
  })(prop);
}
```

and for the cases where some property is referenced without the "window." prefix i can use the with statement , so now i have got something like that:

```
(function(window) {
  with (window) {
    //Some third-party js
  }
})(wrapper);
```

but that seems a bit unnecessary to create a wrapper for the entire window object to just handle the read-only properties , i can use just the "with" statement but if there is a call to "window.top" that won't work, so what do you think? any better alternative from the one i mentioned above?

2. In some situations some js code on the main window object will call global properties created by the third party js that we are running in the iframe and because of that the created properties will exist on the iframe window object and not on the top window object, so for example if our third party js will do something like that:

   window.SomeProp = { "very" : function(){}; , "useful" : function(){}, "prop" : function(){}}

our code on the top window will not be able to use this property, if i know the property name in advance i can wrap it and "proxy" the calls to the iframe property but that's for specific cases and i'm looking for a generic one , so do you think there is a way to observe new properties creation?

Comment: Everything is inside `window` so wrapping window inside something else make no sense, besides there is fastter ES6 way to do it: `const wrapper = {...window};` And `with` keyword is deprecated and in `use strict;` forbidden.

Comment: Your code is running at the same privilege level as the code you're trying to sandbox - ie in the browser.  It's probably likely that with enough effort, any attempt you make to sandbox it can be undone by the code you're trying to sandbox (unless you run a full-fledged JS interpreter yourself).  Can you explain _why_ you want to sandbox it in this fashion, perhaps you're asking the wrong question?

Comment: @Zydnar "with" statement is not deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) and i think you misunderstood me.

Comment: @JamesThorpe you're right but i'm trying to sandbox it that way because i need the third-party code to have access to some dom api's but not for example the document.cookie or such.

Comment: @avidahan what you exactly want to prevent by doing so (by hiding from 3rd party libs some objects/props)?

Comment: @avidahan can you say the names of 3rd party libraries, maybe you think about it in a wrong way? Is it inside something like Selenium and you run some js script? How far can you modify this page - can you opt out from iframe?

Answer (score 1):

I criticized you then I faced similar problem. So I made some upgrade to the code from this blog you provided:

```
var FakeWindow = /** @class */ (function () {
    function FakeWindow() {
        return this.prepare();
    }
    FakeWindow.prototype.prepare = function () {
        var wrapper = {};
        for (var _i = 0, _a = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).sort(); _i < _a.length; _i++) {
            var prop = _a[_i];
            (function (prop) {
                if (typeof (window[prop]) === 'function') {
                    wrapper[prop] = function () { return window[prop].apply(window, arguments); };
                }
                else {
                    Object.defineProperty(wrapper, prop, {
                        'get': function () {
                            if (window[prop] === window) {
                                return wrapper;
                            }
                            else {
                                return window[prop];
                            }
                        },
                        'set': function (value) { wrapper[prop] = value; }
                    });
                }
            })(prop);
        }
        return wrapper;
    };
    return FakeWindow;
}());
```

Notice it's now `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)` instead `prop in window` cause many props are missed by using `prop in window`:

```
let count = 0;
for(prop in window){count++} //count is 270
```

And my way:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).length //846
```

*Number of props may vary depending on browser and active addons*
So basicly to wrap 3rd party lib in some fake window object I do somthing like:

```
const F = new FakeWindow();
(function{const window = F;return /* here goes library content */}).bind(F)()
```

You may need to wrap it in `eval()` to not execute content of lib before binding it to `FakeWindow`.

For some libraries it's needed only bind without `const window...`.
Tested on ThreeJS and jQuery.